# React JS - Select, Why I'm getting double values printed and stored in the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Okay I have a question why when someone clicks on multiple selects answers it does store all the value instead of only storing the last value ?

So let's say I have a select with 2 options only

[image]

And then I click on option 1 but decided to change to option 2 at last minute why does it save both data/information in the database ?

[image]

It prints like this in the table:
[image]

As you can see it does print both schools ("colegios") because I clicked both of them in the select.

This is the snip of code that is relevant, let me know if need full code.

```
const [idType1, setidType1] = useState([]);

const register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const docRef = db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes').doc();
        docRef.set({
            
          name: firstName + " " + lastName,
          school: idType1,
          grade: idType2,
          uid: docRef.id,

        }).then((r) => {
            history.push("/Inicio");
        })
      }

<select className = "crear_escuela" onChange = {(e) => setidType1([...idType1, e.target.value])} required>
   <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Seleccione...</option>
   <option value = 'Academia Internacional de Boquete' label = 'Academia Internacional de Boquete' />
   <option value = 'Academia Internacional de David' label = 'Academia Internacional de David' />
</select>
```

Comment: You are concatenating the values in your `onChange`

Comment: If you can't select more than one item, why is the state even an array?

Comment: @EmileBergeron That's what I saw on a tutorial and I though it was working correctly until I noticed that it was storing multiple data.

Comment: @MinusFour Oh well that makes sense, still new to react so I didn't even knew that meant concatenate in React, thank you I'll see if I can fix it now.

Comment: @MinusFour this is concatenating as well ? 

onChange = {(e) => setidType1(e.target.value)}

Comment: It's not really concatentation, but more just appending new values to an an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `onChange = {(e) => setidType1([...idType1, e.target.value])`.

Every time the value in the `select` changes, you **add** the selected value to `idType1`. Given that this is a dropdown, you'll typically want to replace the existing value of `idType1` with the newly selected value.

So:

```
onChange = { (e) => setidType1(e.target.value) }
```

Comment: Yeah I did that after someone corrected me that I was concatenating thank you very much.